# Python: Converting a nested Dictionary object into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a dictionary in the below format:

```
d = \
  {
  'indent_insert': {1000037121: [('0 - Success',)], 1000037122: [('0 - Success',)]},
  'indent_detail_insert': {1000037121: [('0 - Success',)], 1000037122: [('22051 - duplicate key violation error',)]}
  }
```

This is not JSON per say as it has no `"` around `['0 - Success',)]`. The above is being generated from the below code snippets:

```
key = ['indent_insert','indent_detail_insert']
result = []
indent_lst = ['1000037121','1000037122']
c_indlts_l = [('0-Success'),('22051 - duplicate key violation error')]
c_ind_l = [('0-Success'),('0-Success')]
indtls_results = dict(zip(indent_lst,c_indlts_l))
ind_result = dict(zip(indent_lst,c_ind_l))
result.append(ind_result)
result.append(indtls_results)
d = dict(zip(key,result))
```

Now I want a dataframe like below:

```
IndentNo     indent_insert     indent_details_insert
1000037121   ('0-Success')        ('0 - Success')
1000037122   ('0-Success')        ('22051 - duplicate key violation error')
```

In order to achieve the same I am trying the following:

```
with open(os.path.join(dir_path,f_ind),'r') as f_r:
  d = f_r.read()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

I am getting

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

What I am missing out here.

Comment: your snippet does not reproduce exactly the same structure as the given dictionary (and there is a typo) which one is the right structure?

Comment: @Ben.T: I have edited the question.

Comment: @Corralien: It is clearly mentioned in question. My input is `d` and my output is the dataframe.

Comment: @Corralien: Ah!! gotcha!!. I have edited the question. Thanks for pointed that out.

Comment: yes. I have also updated the question further.

Comment: @Ben.T : Please consider `d` being the correct structure.

Comment: Share the exact content of your file, please.

Comment: @Corralien: `d` is the exact content. but in `.txt` format

Comment: Are you completely sure that `d` is a dictionary? At the beginning of the question you are constructing `d` as dictionary: good.  But then in another part of the code you are reading a file and doing `d = f_r.read()` which makes `d` definitely not a dictionary. And then you are calling a method that expects a dictionary. That would never work, since `d` is not a dictionary.

Comment: Please see the actual file below in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file content a dict-like string, use `literal_eval` from `ast` module:

```
import ast

with open('log_indent.log') as f_r:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f_r.read())
    df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for k, v in data.items() if isinstance(v, dict)})
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
             indent_insert indent_detail_insert
1000037121  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037122  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037123  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037124  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000034565  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000034566  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000039683  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000039684  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1400028290  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000038541  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037155  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037156  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037157  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037158  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000033191  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000038190  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000038191  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000038192  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037937  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000038193  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1400028211  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037062  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000038864  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037470  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037471  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037472  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037473  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037474  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037475  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037476  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1000037477  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1400028259  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1400015221  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
1400024437  (0 - Success,)       (0 - Success,)
```

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering`

Comment: I updated my answer but I really don't understand your error. Can you share your file to understand if there is special characters inside, please?

Comment: How can I share the file?

Comment: wetransfer, dropbox or any other solutions.

Comment: Here it goes. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4ecac049f2bfb101917a0bddcef7fc3d20211206135923/48832f

Comment: Ok. I will update my answer later. It should not be difficult. The problem is because you have not the same length for each entry of your dict.

Comment: @pythondumb. Sorry for the late. I updated my answer. With your file, I was able to turn out your dict to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

[pd.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) expects a dict input, not a string:

```py
import json
with open(os.path.join(dir_path,f_ind),'r') as f_r:
  j_s = f_r.read()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(j_s))
```

Comment: As I have mentioned that `d` is not a JSON. Therefore `json.loads(j_s)` will throw an error like `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`.

Comment: Can you parse with `json.loads( j_s.replace('"', '\''))`?

Comment: Not working. Same error.

Comment: you already have the dictionary, so you don't need any JSON loading. Just do `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: I have updated the question. This is the OP. So `from_dict(d)` and earlier `from_dict(j_s)` are same thing.